# Convert Java Code with RecylcerView in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to convert this Java Code in Kotlin. I have a recycler view, whose elements gets loaded through a call to an external database. In Java, the first thing I usually do, is initializing the recycler view in the OnCreateView (after the view) and then create an adapter with the new elements, just like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popular_fragment, container, false);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.popular_rc_view);
    loadMovie();
    return view;
}

private void loadMovie() {
    ApiService apiService = ApiBuilder.getClient(getContext()).create(ApiService.class);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    Call<MovieResponse> call = ....
    //HERE I LOAD THE DATA INTO "MOVIES"
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new PopularAdapter(movies, R.layout.content_main, getContext()));
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(.....)
}
```

Now, in Kotlin, I tried to do the same thing by initializing on this way:

```
@JvmField
@BindView(R.id.rc_view)
var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popular_fragment, container, false)
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.popular_rc_view)
    loadMovie()
    return view
}

private fun loadMovie() {
    val apiService = getClient(context)!!.create(ApiService::class.java)
    recyclerView!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    val call = ....
    //HERE I LOAD THE DATA INTO "MOVIES"
    recyclerView!!.adapter = PopularAdapter(movies as List<MovieModel>, R.layout.content_main, context!!)
    recyclerView!!.addOnItemTouchListener(....)
}
```

The problem is that in Kotlin I get the error on the PopularAdapter, specifically a **KotlinNullPointerException** on the **onBindViewHolder**. This is my method in the adapter, I get the error on the first line so I think it is a layout problem since it cannot find where to set the text (if I try the print the movie title it works, so it's not a problem of the list):

```
class MoviesAdapter(private val movies: List<MovieModel>, private val rowLayout: Int, private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MovieViewHolder>() {

    class MovieViewHolder(v: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v!!) {
        @JvmField
        @BindView(R.id.movieTitle)
        var movieTitle: TextView? = null

        @JvmField
        @BindView(R.id.date)
        var date: TextView? = null

        @JvmField
        @BindView(R.id.popularityTextView)
        var popularity: TextView? = null

        @JvmField
        @BindView(R.id.gambar)
        var backbg: ImageView? = null

        init {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, v!!)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MovieViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.row, viewGroup, false)
        return MovieViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.movieTitle!!.text = movies[position].title
        val time = movies[position].releaseDate
        val parser = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        var date: Date? = null
        try {
            date = parser.parse(time)
            val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMM yyyy")
            val formattedDate = formatter.format(date)
            holder.date!!.text = formattedDate
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        holder.popularity!!.text = movies[position].getVoteAverage().toString()
        Glide.with(context).load(BuildConfig.URL_BACKBG + movies[position].backdropPath)
                .into(holder.backbg)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return movies.size
    }
}
```

I also post the two xml I used in Java/Kotlin, maybe I need to modify how I declare them into the recycler:

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/logoss"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottombar"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/bottombar"
            android:background="@color/dark"
            android:orientation="vertical">
                <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/BottomNavigation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    app:itemBackground="@color/dark"
                    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:itemTextColor="@animator/bottom_nav_color"
                    app:itemIconTint="@animator/bottom_nav_color"
                    app:menu="@menu/bottombar_menu_4items"/>

        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**popular_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/_150sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/popular_rc_view">
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the decompiled bytecode: [link](https://pastebin.com/ZhvxV2MX)
This is after converting the decompiled bytecode in Java: [java](https://pastebin.com/tudXLcrg)

Comment: I'd suspect it's an issue with `Butterknife` not being able to inject the `movieTitle`. As a first step I would check the Decompiled Kotlin Bytecode if it looks alright.

Comment: The Java version of this project works, now that I'm trying to convert it in Kotlin I got this strange problem.

Comment: Due to a different "nature" of Kotlin fields (e.g. `movieTitle` in the `MovieViewHolder`), annotations (like `@BindView`) might need some extra work. That's why I suggest looking through the `Decompiled` code in the `Show Kotlin Bytecode` feature in Android Studio.

Comment: @BartekLipinski I updated the question with the link with the decompiled byteocde of the Adapter

Comment: @BartekLipinski I also added the java conversion of that bytecode